# Drupal Website showing only some images

Tags: .htaccess

I was told to migrate a Drupal website, but I've never worked with it before so I'm having some difficulties here. I'm trying to run the site in *localhost/myfolder*.

**The URL generated for images is:**

```
/sites/default/files/images/myFile.jpg
```

**The link is broken because it should be:**

```
myfolder/sites/default/files/images/myFile.jpg
```

***I have this on my sites/default/settings.php file:***

```
$base_url = 'http://localhost/myfolder';  // NO trailing slash!
```

***I also added this to my myfolder/.htaccess file:***

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myFolder
```

I ran out of ideas, any help would be deeply apprecciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `RewriteBase /myFolder` directive doesn't do anything to fix the problem you describe. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446835/htaccess-to-redirect-images/15447517#15447517), might be helpful.

Comment: What happens if you change that settings.php line to: `$base_url = '/myfolder';` to get rid of the localhost domain (which won't exist outside of your test rig)?

Answer (score 0):

While migrating a site from a local instance to a staging instance there is always such problems of links of the images. we normally give **myfolder/sites/default/files/images/myFile.jpg** but while migrating to staging instance it should be **/sites/default/files/images/myFile.jpg** so that the server could trace the images.

If we use give **myfolder/sites/default/files/images/myFile.jpg** it would work fine within your local instance but while on staging it wont get loaded.

So always give **/sites/default/files/images/myFile.jpg** so that there is no problem....

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the following code.

```
$src = base_path() . path_to_theme() . 'images/myFile.jpg';

<img src= <?php echo $src; ?> />
```